# accessing hard drive - have been trying for days

Tags: hard-drive

I have spent days reading everything I came across in the attempt to Access files from my internal hard drive on a Windows 7 Computer that no longer works.

I don't know what the Problem is.  I finally got a USB stick with Ubuntu 14.04 on it and that seems to work just fine.
  I cannot Access my hard drive.  It might be there but I don't know.  I see a 4.1 GB hard Disk (/dev/sda) in devices from disks.  But I just don't know how to Access it.

I somehow managed to get to: root@ubuntu:~# but don't know what to do from there, if anything.  Is there any place where a complete Computer idiot can get step by step, easy to follow instructions?

I would really like to Access my hard drive and pull a couple files off it before it gets sent in to the shop.
  I really don't have much Computer knowledge but would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you see the Ubuntu desktop when you boot from the ubuntu USB ?

Answer (score 0):

When you start up the computer using the Ubuntu USB, click the Try Ubuntu button to get to a desktop.

As long as your hard drive is functioning property, and as long as your Windows 7 installation is not encrypted, these steps should work to access your documents:

1. Click on the folder icon on the left-hand side to open the file browser.
2. Under the "Devices" section on the left, click on your hard drive.  It should be named something like "XX GB Filesystem."
   [image]
3. You should see the files in your C: drive.  Navigate to Users\Documents and Settings\(username) and you should see your personal documents.